# Big-O notation between while loop

Tags: python, big-o

Help finding the big-Oh notation for the following code:

```
i = n
while i > 0:
    k = 2 + 2
    i = i // 2
```

I think its `n` because `n` is assigned and then looped. Is this right?

Comment: Think about how many times the loop body is executed. That's roughly your complexity (and on a von Neumann computer, time) estimate.

Comment: Firstly, assume that `n` is a power of two. Then take some `n` and write down `i`'s values at every iteration of the loop. It's sometimes useful to try some "good" values firstly, especially at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to think of this (which can be used as a general approach) is the following:

- the initial value of `i` is `n`
- the code will stop looping once i reaches 0 (consequently, the last iteration will execute when `i` is 1)
- having executed an arbitrary number of iterations (call that number `c`), the value of `i` is

  ```
   ((n / 2) / 2) / ... )     = n / (2 ^ c) 
       ^ divide by 2 c times
  ```

So, at the end of the loop, we want `(n / (2 ^ c)) = 1`. Solving for `c` gives us `c = logn`.

So the big-oh complexity is `O(logn)`. (That is, assuming `n` is an integer and not a float).

Comment: Would be right if it was integer. But is it? It's not defined, thus I assumed it can be a float as well.

Comment: @benjist I think your reasoning is incorrect. Anyway, I suggest you to build a test case. Even if i was float, which I think is not the case, i eventually will reach zero. Of course, it could repeat more times

Comment: @lrleon I was wrong because this is indeed about integer division. And you are right that it will eventually reach zero when you write a test case for it, even if it was a float division. But for floats the float would just reach 0 because of floating point precision for most languages - but in theory it will never reach 0 because you can always divide by 2 infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

The loop repeats the number of times that you can divide n by two. That is O(log n).

Comment: If you don't see why, consider that if you double a large value of n, you add one to the number of times the loop runs.